# STL Algorithm that Takes a Test and Mutate Function

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl, lambda

What I want is this behavior: `void change_if( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, UnaryPredicate test, UnaryOperation op )`

Is the best way to achieve that just with a for loop? Or is there some STL magic I don't yet know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution by [Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow) is the recommended approach for it's simplicity.

The "seemingly obious" use of the `std::transform` standard algorithm with a lambda:

```
std::transform(first, last, first, [](auto elem) {
   return test(elem) ? op(elem) : elem;
});
```

actually leads to performance degradation because *all* elements will be assigned to, not just those satisfying the predicate. To only modify the predicated elements, one would also need something like `boost::filter_iterator` as mentioned in the answer by kiwi.

Note that I used C++14 syntax with the `auto` inside the lambda. For C++11, you would need something like `decltype(*first)` or `iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type`. And in C++98/03 you would both that and a hand made function object.

Comment: Note that the type inference stuff is only necessary if you're actually parameterizing your code on the container's element type.

Comment: How are you using C++14, are there even compilers for that yet?

Comment: @JonathanMee Clang 3.4 is feature complete, and both Visual Studio 2013 November CTP and soon to be released gcc 4.9 also supports generic lambdas. Note: technically it's still called c++1y, but in 2014 many features are already here!

Answer (score 7):

This can be done without using boost but applying standard algorithm `std::for_each`
I do not advice to use boost for such simple tasks. It is simply a stupidy to include boost in your project that to perform such a simple task. You may use boost for such tasks provided that it is already included in your project.

```
std::for_each( first, last, []( const T &x ) { if ( test( x ) ) op( x ); } );
```

Or you can remove the qualifier const  if you are going to change elements of the sequence

```
std::for_each( first, last, []( T &x ) { if ( test( x ) ) op( x ); } );
```

Sometimes when the whole range of a sequence is used it is simpler to use the range based for statement instead of an algorithm becuase using algorithms with lambda expressions sometimes makes code less readable

```
for ( auto &x : sequence )
{
   if ( test( x ) ) op( x );
}
```

Or

```
for ( auto &x : sequence )
{
   if ( test( x ) ) x = op( x );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Still another boost solution :

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html

Just call std::transform on your filtered iterator.

Comment: I do have access to boost, but I fail to see how this would be better than a for loop?

Comment: It won't be, this is juste an alternative. Using algorithm such as `for_each`, `transform` ... will just hide the actual for loop that can be implemented in many different ways (concurrent programming ...)

Comment: After properly reading it over I can see how this would make for a very elegant solution. I misunderstood what it was doing on my first pass. Can I use this iterator right in stl, or do I need to use a Boost algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

```
std::for_each( first, last, []( T &x ) { if ( test( x ) ) op( x ); } );
```

or using boost lambda:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/if.hpp>

std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), 
                   if_( test() )[ op() ] 
                 );
```

alternatively:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();
while ( it != v.end()) {
  if ( test( *it)) op(*it);
  ++it;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the alternatively solution is the one I'm using, except in a C++11 `for` loop not a `while` statement. The boost `if` is interesting though, I haven't seen that before.

Answer (score 1):

You want `change_if` as a simple loop?

```
template<typename ForwardIterator, typename UnaryPredicate>
void change_if( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, UnaryPredicate test, UnaryOperation op ) {
  for(; first!=last; ++first)
    if (test(*first)) *first=op(std::move(*first));
}
```

or just write the above loop.  I would advise actually writing `change_if` and calling it, because while the above code is short I would find the `change_if` call to be more, not less, clear than just dropping the above code in.

I also like writing container-based overloads:

```
template<typename Container, typename UnaryPredicate>
void change_if( Container&& c, UnaryPredicate test, UnaryOperation op ) {
  for(auto& v : std::forward<Container>(c))
    if (test(v)) v=op(std::move(v));
}
```

but I also have this:

```
template<typename Iterator>
struct range {
  Iterator b, e;
  Iterator begin() const { return b; }
  Iterator end() const { return e; }
};
template<typename Iterator0, typename Iterator1>
range<typename std::decay<Iterator0>::type> make_range(Iterator0&& b, Iterator1&& e) {
  static_assert(
    std::is_convertible< Iterator1, typename std::decay<Iterator0>::type >::value,
    "end must be compatible with begin iterator type"
  );
  return { std::forward<Iterator0>(b), std::forward<Iterator1>(e) };
}
```

which lets me use such container-based algorithms with iterators.

You'll see I have a `Container` based `change_if`?  It is really a range-based `change_if`.

It is called like:

```
change_if( myVect, [](int x){return (x%2)==0;}, [](int x){return x/2;} );
```

on a container, not a pair of iterators.  However, if you only want to change the first half of a container, it doesn't work: so at first glance, container-based (well, range-based) algorithms are less useful.

But `make_range` turns iterators into a range.  So you can:

```
change_if( make_range( myVec.begin(), myVec.begin()+myVec.size()/2 ), [](int x){return (x%2)==0;}, [](int x){return x/2;} )
```

`make_range` fills in the inability to directly pass 2 iterators to range-based algorithms by bundling two iterators into one `range<>` object.  This corner case is more verbose, but the typical case (of processing an entire container) becomes less verbose.

Plus, a common kind of error (naming a different container for `begin` and `end`) is made far less frequent.

All of this ends up being as efficient, or more so, than the iterator-based version.  And, if you replace your ranges with iterables (ranges that have dissimilar `begin` and `end` iterator types), my `change_if` just works

Comment: came back to read over some unselected answers to my questions, and I was hoping to get some clarification on your answer. You use several calls that I don't recognize their usage, from C++11?

1) forward

2) decay

3) is_convertable

Comment: @jonathanmee `forward` is a conditional `move` that is useful in some contexts: the pattern is called perfect forwarding.  `decay` emulates how types decay when turned into a 'stored' value, like function references to function pointers, arrays to pointers, or cv qualified to not, or references to values.  `is_convertable` is a trait whose `::value` is `true` iff one type passed to it can be converted to the other (it is directiinal).

Comment: OK, so I still don't follow how make_range will help us to selectively change contents.

Comment: @jonathanmee answer augmented with answer to your query.  Oh and a typo/bug fixed.

Comment: So this also clears up for me why you used forward. +1 for taking the time to explain this all.